# Can I install a floor length window on the second floor?

Tags: windows, building-regulations

I live in Hillsborough, North Carolina. I am redoing a bedroom and would like to install a floor length window but I'm not sure if it will meet the regulations. The width is 31.5 inches and the length would be about 72 inches

Comment: The window is in the wall, right?  I understand a window that is 31.5" wide, but I'm not sure what a window 72" long looks like? Measurements on a wall would be width, height, and maybe thickness.

Comment: Without knowing more about the structure of the building (how many floors for starters), it's impossible to say for sure if you can do what you want easily. I'm sure it's *possible*, but it would take a structural engineer on site to be able to tell you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It used to be that such a window had to have tempered safety glass, now:

2006 IRC:

R613.2 Window Sills. In dwelling units, where the opening of an operable window is located more than 72 inches above the finished grade or surface below, the lowest part of the clear opening of the window shall be a minimum of 24 inches above the finished floor of the room in which the window is located. Glazing between the floor and 24 inches shall be fixed or have openings through which a 4-inch-diameter sphere cannot pass.

So, no part of the window that actually opens can be lower than 24" unless barricaded similar to balcony railings (4" dia. ball test). Fixed glazing is allowed but must be tempered safety glass if extending below 18" height on the wall. It is easy to order your windows with tempered glass, it just costs a bit more. Check with your window supplier as they will be familiar with the code requirements and any additional restrictions in your area.